# Hiding a specific object of a catalog results

Tags: plone, catalog

There is a way to hide a specific object of my catalog results?
I have a configuration file that I don't want to show.
I'm filtering by id, but it seems so ugly.

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
def search(context):
    catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
    items = catalog()
    for item in items:
        if item.id != "config_file":
            'do something'
```

Comment: There are several ways to not have your items show up in the search results, but they all are aimed at different use-cases. Don't show in the navigation tree, don't show when you don't have permission, etc. What is your use case?

Comment: Really I was not very clear. I'm doing a simple view that shows news, the user have permission to see the object, but I don't want to show it. I've already hid the object in the navigation tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already hiding the object from the navigation tree, you can filter on the same property by testing for `exclude_from_nav`:

```
items = catalog()
for item in items:
    if item.exclude_from_nav:
        continue

    # do something with all objects *not* excluded from navigation.
```

It is harder to filter out things that *don't* match a criteria. Using a test on the brain object like the above is a perfectly fine way to remove a small subset from your result set.

If you need handle a larger percentage of 'exceptions' you'll need to rethink your architecture, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

With [Products.AdvancedQuery](http://www.dieter.handshake.de/pyprojects/zope/AdvancedQuery.html) you can create advanced queries and filtering on catalog results. See also this [how to](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/searching-with-advancedquery).

Comment: I didn't know this product. It seems good, but in this case I think it's unnecessary. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, setting a content item's expiration date to some past date hides it from search results (so long as the user does not have the *Access inactive portal content* permission).

It's an easy way to hide pieces of content that should be visible to all, but that you don't want cluttering up search results e.g. a Document that serves as the homepage.

I always use *1st Jan 2001* as the date so I can easily recognise when I've used this little 'hack'.